# How to load unique items of a specific excel column to a combo box using c#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm new to EPPlus excel library. Recently I've been trying to figure out a efficient way to load all unique items from the first column of a excel file (apart from the very first cell as it is the title) to a combo box on form load. I've tried below but it's not working (its showing the text System.Linq.Enumerable+d__64`1[System.Char] in the combo box) & also I want to dynamically find the last filled row number of the first column and not just manually add it in the code like I did i.e. 10:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Tamal Banerjee\Desktop\sample.xlsx"));
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
var start = workSheet.Dimension.Start;

    for (int row = start.Row; row <= 10; row++)
    {           
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[row, 1].Text.ToString()))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(workSheet.Cells[row, 1].Text.Distinct().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You may want to add all items to a `List<string>` and use the `Distinct()` method on the list after, to use the results as the DataSource of your ComboBox (`[TheList].Distinct().ToList()`, you cannot use an `IEnumerable<string>` as source)

Comment: @Jimi I replaced `comboBox1.Items.Add(workSheet.Cells[row, 1].Text.Distinct().ToString());` to `party.Add(workSheet.Cells[row, 1].Text);` where `party` is a `List<string>` & then did a `foreach (var element in party)` like `comboBox1.Items.Add(element.Distinct().ToString());` but now its showing `System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__64``1[System.Char]`... What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Also, how do I dynamically find the last filled row number of the first column?

Comment: It's `List<string>.Distinct()`, not `[string].Distinct().ToString()`, `element` is a string, calling `Distinct()` on it generates an `IEnumerable<char>` and this `ToString()` gives you back the name of the Type. -- Not sure what *dynamically find the last filled row number* means. If you're looking for empty Cells, just check the content.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for explaining... By "dynamically find the last filled row number" means I basically want to find the last filled row of the first column automatically without physically checking the file every time as the data will be added / deleted to the source excel file and that row number will change. Hope you understand now.